# add wkt representation of the geometry as field in qgis

Tags: qgis, shapefile, well-known-text

I have the shapefile of boundaries loaded in qgis. I want to add a field in the file which is WKT representation of the feature.

**Update**

As Nathan W answered
I used `geomToWKT( $geometry )` and got result. The thing is the coordinates are in lon lat format. I found out that that i need them in lat lon format. Is it possible to change the order of coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [QGIS 2.0](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) you can use the following function in the field calculator.

```
 geomToWKT( $geometry )
```

Comment: i specified text data type with length 255. I seem to have exceeded that.

Comment: You are going to be restricted to what shapefiles can store unless you use a different format.